# Laravel: What is the best way to implement a method in a model class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a simple search method in my `Game` model and I have implemented it as below.

```
public static function search($season, $week)
{
     $filteredGames = Game::with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
        ->when($season != null, function ($q) {
            return $q->where('season_id', request('season'));
        })->when($week != null, function ($q) {
            return $q->where('week_id', request('week'));
        })
        ->paginate(15);

       return $filteredGames;
}
```

And using it in controller like this

```
$games = Game::search(request('season'), request('week'));
```

Looks like it works perfectly.

I want learn whether using a static method is the best way to implement such a feature in terms of design patterns and SOLID principles or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Eloquent, then you are already violating majority of principles in SOLID. And static methods by their nature are actually procedural (and globally scoped). To actually use SOLID principles in your code, you would have to stop using Laravel. So ... you probably should not fret about it best practices and just focus on finishing the project and picking up the next one (I am assuming you are using Lravle for a small throw-away project).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. But it would be better if you use Repository Pattern

Comment: @tereško I am using Eloquent. Which principles in SOLID I am violating and how ? Thanks.

Comment: @AliN11 thanks, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Tartar sure, here ya go: S - active record contains both persistence and domain logic, it has multiple reasons to change, O - if table structure changes you need to change the class, L - the child class is **not** a specialized case of the superclass, but has new and unrelated  behavior. I and D - the interface is globally scopes, which makes every use of it a hidden dependency

Comment: @tereško thanks for the detailed answer. How would you consider my current implementation in terms of Laravel ?

Comment: I don't know. I prefer avoiding that framework and it's community, since I can't agree with what they [produce](https://laracasts.com/series/php-bits/episodes/1). I would have written a proper answer, if I thought of myself as "expert in laravel".

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @tereško thanks tho your comments were explanatory enough

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to IFR's comment above I changed my implementation to this which I think that the best approach to be for Laravel.

```
public function scopeOfFilter($query, $season, $week)
{
    return $query->with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
        ->when($season != null, function ($q) {
            return $q->where('season_id', request('season'));
        })->when($week != null, function ($q) {
            return $q->where('week_id', request('week'));
        })
        ->paginate(10);
}
```